# HERE Maps Turn-by-Turn Navigation for Indoor 3D Venues supported?

Tags: ios, swift, here-api, here-ios

I am trying to route between two 3D Venue Spaces within a building (Indoors) and Turn-by-Turn Navigation started.

I find out, that there is no way to convert an Route of Type "NMAVenue3dCombinedRoute" into the required "NMARoute" Type to start the Turn-By-Turn-Navigation:

```
NMANavigationManager.shared().startTurnByTurnNavigation(with: NMARoute!)
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With current SDK 3.3 no turn by turn guidance for venues is possible, only indoor routing and positioning.

Comment: Maybe in one of the next release?

Comment: It's fore sure the next logical step after routing and positioning, and something the team in general also looks into, but I can't comment on any potential release date of this feature at the moment.